# Magento2 Related Products Block Based On Customer Interest

Tags: magento2, module, related-products

I have a magento2 website and what i am thinking is i want to develop a related products block which needs to be displayed based on user interest.

Lets assume a user open my website firstly and then clicked on any product then i want to show a random products under related products.

If the same user used any filter or search keyword as "black" then i want to show related products based on that black keyword only.

I almost checked all the available magento2 modules by mageplaza or webkul or cedcommerce but none of them providing this feature.

I want to know is that search history or filter history storing in any database table? If yes based on user browser history how can i get the related products?